# Is there a Regex to split string: "#CAT - meow meow #DOG - bark bark #FOX - what does it say?" on #XXX while keeping #XXX [in Google Scripts]?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I am working on a project in Google Scripts and I am struggling with getting a regex that would allow me to split the string:

```
"#CAT - meow meow #DOG - bark bark #FOX - what does it say?"
```

on #XXX while keeping #XXX in the string.

I have came up with:

```
(?=#[A-Z]{3}.+?(?=#[A-Z]{3}))
```

https://regex101.com/r/e4V0VW/2
but it does not work.

With my regex, I am getting:

```
var str = "#CAT - meow meow #DOG - bark bark #FOX - what does it say?";

console.log(str.split(/(?=#[A-Z]{3}.+?(?=#[A-Z]{3}))/g));

["#CAT - meow meow ", "#DOG - bark bark #FOX - what does it say?"]
0: "#CAT - meow meow "
1: "#DOG - bark bark #FOX - what does it say?"
```

In the browser console and I guess that it will work similarly in Google Scripts.

My goal is to get an array with 3 strings:

```
["#CAT - meow meow", "#DOG - bark bark", "#FOX - what does it say?"]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? :)

Comment: What about `str.split(/(?=#[A-Z]{3})/)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split with `/(?=#[A-Z]{3})/` regex:

```js
var str = "#CAT - meow meow #DOG - bark bark #FOX - what does it say?";
console.log(str.split(/(?=#[A-Z]{3})/))
```

The `(?=#[A-Z]{3})` regex contains a single [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) matches a location in the string that is immediately followed with `#` and then three ASCII uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way:

```
function xsplit() {
  var s="#CAT - meow meow #DOG - bark bark #FOX - what does it say?";
  var idxA=[];
  var fromidx=0;
  do{
    var idx=s.indexOf('#',fromidx);
    if(idx>-1) {
      idxA.push(idx);
      fromidx=idx+1;
    }
  }while(idx>-1);
  var sA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<idxA.length-1;i++) {
    sA.push(s.slice(idxA[i],idxA[i+1]));
  }
  sA.push(s.slice(idxA[idxA.length-1]));
  Logger.log(sA);
  return sA;
}
```